# java multipart upload uploads two times more data

Tags: java, upload, multipart

Hi I am using this to upload files to server. But there is some bug here so it uploads two times more data than the file size.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.HttpCookie;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import static nookauto.CustomFunctions.COOKIES_HEADER;
import static nookauto.CustomFunctions.NEWLINE;
import static nookauto.CustomFunctions.USER_AGENT;
import static nookauto.CustomFunctions.msCookieManager;

/**
 * This utility class provides an abstraction layer for sending multipart HTTP
 * POST requests to a web server.
 * @author www.codejava.net
 *
 */
public class MultipartUtility {
    private final String boundary;
    private static final String LINE_FEED = "\r\n";
    private HttpURLConnection httpConn;
    private String charset;
    private OutputStream outputStream;
    private PrintWriter writer;
    private String header;
    private int responseCode;

    /**
     * This constructor initializes a new HTTP POST request with content type
     * is set to multipart/form-data
     * @param requestURL
     * @param charset
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public MultipartUtility(String requestURL, String charset)
            throws IOException {
        this.charset = charset;

        // creates a unique boundary based on time stamp
        boundary = "===" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "===";

        URL url = new URL(requestURL);
        httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpConn.setUseCaches(false);
        httpConn.setDoOutput(true); // indicates POST method
        httpConn.setDoInput(true);
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
        //httpConn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "CodeJava Agent");
        //httpConn.setRequestProperty("Test", "Bonjour");
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
            //conn.setRequestProperty( "Cookie", cookies);
            if(msCookieManager.getCookieStore().getCookies().size() > 0)
            {
                //While joining the Cookies, use ',' or ';' as needed. Most of the server are using ';'
                String cookiess = "";

                for (HttpCookie s : msCookieManager.getCookieStore().getCookies())
                {
                    cookiess += s + "; ";
                }
                //System.out.println("cookieee: " + cookiess);
                httpConn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookiess);    
                //conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", TextUtils.join(";",  msCookieManager.getCookieStore().getCookies()));    
            }
        outputStream = httpConn.getOutputStream();
        writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, charset),
                true);
    }

    /**
     * Adds a form field to the request
     * @param name field name
     * @param value field value
     */
    public void addFormField(String name, String value) {
        //System.out.println(name+"="+value);
        writer.append("--" + boundary).append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + name + "\"")
                .append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=" + charset).append(
                LINE_FEED);
        writer.append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append(value).append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.flush();
    }

    /**
     * Adds a upload file section to the request
     * @param fieldName name attribute in <input type="file" name="..." />
     * @param uploadFile a File to be uploaded
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public void addFilePart(String fieldName, File uploadFile)
            throws IOException {
        String fileName = uploadFile.getName();
        writer.append("--" + boundary).append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append(
                "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + fieldName
                        + "\"; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"")
                .append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append(
                "Content-Type: "
                        + URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(fileName))
                .append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary").append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.flush();

        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(uploadFile);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead = -1;
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        outputStream.flush();
        inputStream.close();

        writer.append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.flush();    
    }

    /**
     * Adds a header field to the request.
     * @param name - name of the header field
     * @param value - value of the header field
     */
    public void addHeaderField(String name, String value) {
        writer.append(name + ": " + value).append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.flush();
    }

    /**
     * Completes the request and receives response from the server.
     * @return a list of Strings as response in case the server returned
     * status OK, otherwise an exception is thrown.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public List<String> finish() throws IOException {
        List<String> response = new ArrayList<String>();

        writer.append(LINE_FEED).flush();
        writer.append("--" + boundary + "--").append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.close();

        StringBuilder header = new StringBuilder();
        int headerIdx = 0;
        String headerKey = null;
        String headerValue = null;
        while ( (headerValue = httpConn.getHeaderField(headerIdx)) != null ) {
          headerKey = httpConn.getHeaderFieldKey(headerIdx);
          if (headerKey != null && headerKey.length()>0) {
            header.append(headerKey);
            header.append(" : ");
          }
          header.append(headerValue);
          header.append(NEWLINE);
          headerIdx++;
        }
        setHeader(header.toString());

        // checks server's status code first
        Map<String, List<String>> headerFields = httpConn.getHeaderFields();
        List<String> cookiesHeader = headerFields.get(COOKIES_HEADER);

        if(cookiesHeader != null)
        {
            for (String cookie : cookiesHeader) 
            {
              msCookieManager.getCookieStore().add(null,HttpCookie.parse(cookie).get(0));
            }               
        }
        int status = httpConn.getResponseCode();
        setResponseCode(status);
        if (status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    httpConn.getInputStream()));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                response.add(line);
            }
            reader.close();
            httpConn.disconnect();
        } else {
            throw new IOException("Server returned non-OK status: " + status);
        }

        return response;
    }
    private void setHeader(String header){
        this.header = header;
    }
    public String getHeader(){
        return this.header;
    }

    private void setResponseCode(int responseCode){
        this.responseCode = responseCode;
    }
    public int getResponseCode(){
        return this.responseCode;
    }
}
```

Please help what is wrong here. I get this code from here http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/upload-files-by-sending-multipart-request-programmatically
and modified it.

If anybody knows how to get it work normally please help.

Comment: For example if you upload 3 MB file, 6 MB data will be transfered.

Comment: What have you done to debug it?

Comment: don't know where to start to debug

Comment: Found that it's happening because I am connecting to Https protocol.